# Listing contents of classes in Java

Tags: java

Folks, is there somewhere on the Net where I can find a list of the contents of standard Java classes?
Say I wanted to know what functions the class Math contains. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Just feeling my way as a beginner. Sorry for the dumb question :-)

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: That would be the javadoc.Google search 'javadocs' and you will see the first result is the information you are looking for.

Comment: Google the classname and read the Javadoc. (e.g. "Java Math")

Comment: Sorry for being offtopic, but you should say "methods" instead of "functions".

Comment: No probs. Thanks for putting me straight. Learning the language too :-)

Comment: Why are all the answers pointing to ye olde Java SE 6?

Comment: It's plenty for me to be getting on with. While I'm learning, I just want an idea of what basic classes contain. Thanks to all for the rapid and non-patronising answers :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's programmers around the globe helping each other.

Comment: Thanks Mike! It's been a long time since I looked at Java, and as soon as someone pointed out where the info was, I put my dufus cap on :-) Brilliant to get help so quickly, and look forward to asking more complicated questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oracle [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to Internet or JavaDoc, `javap` utility is at your rescue. It comes bundled with JDK.

This is how you use it

```
C:\>javap java.lang.Math
Compiled from "Math.java"
public final class java.lang.Math {
  public static final double E;
  public static final double PI;
  public static double sin(double);
  public static double cos(double);
  public static double tan(double);
  public static double asin(double);
  public static double acos(double);
  public static double atan(double);
  public static double toRadians(double);
  public static double toDegrees(double);
  public static double exp(double);
  public static double log(double);
  public static double log10(double);
  public static double sqrt(double);
  public static double cbrt(double);
  public static double IEEEremainder(double, double);
  public static double ceil(double);
  public static double floor(double);
  public static double rint(double);
  public static double atan2(double, double);
  public static double pow(double, double);
  public static int round(float);
  public static long round(double);
  public static double random();
  public static int abs(int);
  public static long abs(long);
  public static float abs(float);
  public static double abs(double);
  public static int max(int, int);
  public static long max(long, long);
  public static float max(float, float);
  public static double max(double, double);
  public static int min(int, int);
  public static long min(long, long);
  public static float min(float, float);
  public static double min(double, double);
  public static double ulp(double);
  public static float ulp(float);
  public static double signum(double);
  public static float signum(float);
  public static double sinh(double);
  public static double cosh(double);
  public static double tanh(double);
  public static double hypot(double, double);
  public static double expm1(double);
  public static double log1p(double);
  public static double copySign(double, double);
  public static float copySign(float, float);
  public static int getExponent(float);
  public static int getExponent(double);
  public static double nextAfter(double, double);
  public static float nextAfter(float, double);
  public static double nextUp(double);
  public static float nextUp(float);
  public static double scalb(double, int);
  public static float scalb(float, int);
  static {};
}

C:\>
```

Comment: Thanks! There's always more than one way to do it...

Comment: You welcome! :) Please don't forget to mark your question answered once you are satisfied with any of the answers.

Comment: Ahh, thought I had, when I ticked someone's response. Do I have to tick each response, or is there a single option to close off the question as answered?

Comment: You accept one answer, but you can upvote others if they were also useful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Haven't enough reputation to upvote yet (this is Day 1 for me!), but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You cand find all methods in all standard java classes here : [Java API Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)